# Perfect Secrecy of AES file Encryption

Tags: aes, provable-security, perfect-secrecy

Why does AES file encryption not ensure perfect secrecy?

I understand that $\Pr[E(K,M_1)=C_1] = \Pr[E(K,M_2)=C_2]$ given $M1\neq M2$ holds for perfect secrecy of a scheme.
However, this seems to hold for any message with AES.

Comment: Hint: What is the required property for perfect secrecy concerning the key and message space?

Comment: KeySpace > MessageSpace !
But the MessageSpace when encrypting files is much larger than the KeySpace and hence, AES will not be effective.
Is that correct ?

Comment: I think, you haven't understood the definition correctly. $\Pr[E(K,M_1)=C] = \Pr[E(K,M_2)=C], \forall M_1,M_2$ and the probability is over all possible keys.